# Launch storyboard

Tags: appdelegate

I am trying to detect at the launch of my app if the device is an iPhone 5 or not. If the device is an iPhone i want to launch my storyboard, else another storyboard. I tried this code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height == 1136){
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone_5" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
    }
}
```

and it seems working but when the app is launched there is only a black screen. I think there is a problem with the storyboard (each storyboard as 2 view controllers with 2 views). I have one of the 2 views as "Initial view controller" but there is always the baclk screen without the correct view.

Anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're code does look correct. The only time I've ever gotten a black screen when launching is when I accidentally deleted the view inside the UIViewController...not sure if this helps. Make sure all your references are correct. If you deleted, re-named, or otherwise changed the names of classes, methods, etc., this can also cause issues.